# Is it OK to ask for CMS recos here (based on site purpose)?

Tags: discussion

I respect the StackExchange sites for offering efficient and effective information flow.  I would rather ask for permission than risk offense.

I am building a site and familiar with (and tired of) a particular CMS.  I'd like to ask for alternatives, based on the particular features / purpose of this new site.

If a "which CMS" question doesn't fit here, I would be grateful for pointers as to where I might get expert advice and save myself some time.

Best,

TC

Comment: IMHO, the "StackExchange" spin off sites are not as harsh as StackOverflow is.  The folks here at UX.SE are very nice, at least ;-)

BTW.  You know that every site has a "Meta"-section, right?  You should ask such meta questions like _this_ in the "Meta" area, just to be on the safe side.

UX.SE is all about _UserExperience_.  You should ask specific questions about UX-related issues.  _What_ characterizes good UX, _how_ to create good UX, UX research, UX dilemmas etc etc.

Comment: Also, FWIW, 'what CMS to use' isn't likely a good fit for any SE site. So much of it will come down to personal opinion.

Answer (score 2):

Questions requesting advice on what software to buy isn't something suitable to this, or any of the Stack Exchange sites. The reason being that as a Q&A website we need questions where you need the correct answer, but there is no correct answer to a 'which is best' question; it's all subjective and even if there *were* a correct answer it's highly likely it won't be correct for long as other newer software will come out and therefore surpass it, making the question obsolete.

Have a read of this stack exchange blog post for more reasoning: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/

As for where you can ask it; that's not something we can recommend. We only deal with the Stack Exchange network, you'll have to look for some cms forums for some advice there but Stack Exchange isn't the place I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

You could always ask for advice on *how* to make the decision of which CMS to choose. Then the question and answers would have use to more people than just yourself - since they'll presumably tell you which criteria are and are not important, etc.

I'm not sure exactly which SE site that question would be best for, though I'm sure someone else can make a good suggestion for you.